# How to work with ZonedDateTime using API Stream?

Tags: java, java-stream, zoneddatetime

I'm trying to pass this method that uses a clasic FOR to a Stream API

```
public static List<DateBucket> bucketize(ZonedDateTime fromDate,ZonedDateTime toDate,   int bucketSize, ChronoUnit bucketSizeUnit) {
      

    List<DateBucket> buckets = new ArrayList<>();
       boolean reachedDate = false;
       for (int i = 0; !reachedDate; i++) {
           ZonedDateTime minDate = fromDate.plus(i * bucketSize, bucketSizeUnit);
           ZonedDateTime maxDate = fromDate.plus((i + 1) * bucketSize, bucketSizeUnit);
           reachedDate = toDate.isBefore(maxDate);
           buckets.add(new DateBucket(minDate.toInstant(), maxDate.toInstant()));
       }

   return buckets;
}
```

something like this:

```
List<DateBucket> buckets = 
    buckets.stream().map(i-> new DateBucket(minDate.toInstant(),maxDate.toInstant()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Thanks

Comment: What version of Java are you using?  This will be much harder in 8 than 9, if it's possible at all.  Also, `bucketSize` and `bucketSizeUnit` together are probably better expressed as a `Period` or `Duration` (`ZonedDateTime` being terrible precisely because it's not obvious which one)

Comment: @LouisWasserman The method might just accept a `TemporalAmount`. It’s an interface that both `Duration` and `Period` implement.

Comment: @OleV.V. While that's true, it's also problematic to conflate a `Duration` and a `Period`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static List<DateBucket> bucketize(ZonedDateTime fromDate,
        ZonedDateTime toDate, int bucketSize, ChronoUnit bucketSizeUnit) {
    return Stream.iterate(fromDate,
                    zdt -> zdt.isBefore(toDate),
                    zdt -> zdt.plus(bucketSize, bucketSizeUnit))
            .map(zdt -> new DateBucket(zdt.toInstant(),
                    zdt.plus(bucketSize, bucketSizeUnit).toInstant()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

To try it out:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Urumqi");
    ZonedDateTime from = ZonedDateTime.of(2020, 8, 18, 9, 0, 0, 0, zone);
    ZonedDateTime to = ZonedDateTime.of(2020, 8, 20, 17, 0, 0, 0, zone);
    
    List<DateBucket> buckets = bucketize(from, to, 1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    buckets.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

> ```
> 2020-08-18T03:00:00Z - 2020-08-19T03:00:00Z
> 2020-08-19T03:00:00Z - 2020-08-20T03:00:00Z
> 2020-08-20T03:00:00Z - 2020-08-21T03:00:00Z
> ```

I’m unsure whether it’s advantageous to use a stream operation here, but as you see, it is certainly possible.

The `iterate` method that I am using was introduced in Java 9.

Comment: Sorry @Ole V.V, I will create another post with the question. thanks for your good answer on this

Comment: It’s OK. It takes a bit to learn to use this site correctly.